# Why I'm getting all database info in some values in mi Symfony 2 REST API?

Tags: json, api, rest, symfony, doctrine

I'm building a REST API with Symfony 2 and I'm getting a very rare problem... I've got a "customers" table in relation OneToMany with another "control" table and if I try to get a customer with values in "control" table what I get is all my database info in JSON format... :S

For example: the customer with id=12 does not have data associated in "control" table, so if I do
http://localhost/Ourentec/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/customers/12
I get the correct JSON

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Zampacontos",
        "lastname": "",
        "address": "",
        "phone": "000000000",
        "pass": "no tiene",
        "tasks": "Portátil Toshiba con cargador y funda negra \"tec air\".\r\n Cambiar pila BIOS y comprobar que no de errores (optimizar) Urgente ",
        "status": "Terminado",
        "email": "",
        "date": "2015-11-06T13:06:00+0100",
        "location": "Tienda",
        "is_active": 0,
        "controls": [],
        "histories": []
    }
}
```

But if I do the same with id=11 (a customer with "controls" and "histories" is when I get all my database info!!!

Any idea?? Thanks in advance :)

EDITED:

Here are my API Controllers for one or all customers:

```
<?php

namespace Ourentec\OurentecApiBundle\Controller\v1;


use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CustomerController extends FOSRestController{
    /**
     * @return array
     * @Rest\Get("/customers/{id}")
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function getCustomerAction($id)
    {
        $customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('OurentecBundle:Customer')->find($id);

        return array('customer' => $customer);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array
     * @Rest\Get("/customers/")
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function getUsersAction()
    {
        $customers = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('OurentecBundle:Customer')->findAll();

        return array('customers' => $customers);
    }
}
```

And if I do a http://localhost/Ourentec/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/customers/ I get all database info too. Even "User" table with, of course, all my users, passwords(encrytped), etc... :O

Comment: Could you show us how you build your queries?
What "all my database info" mean?

Comment: Edited in main post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of different behaviour of `find` and `findAll` methods.

Under the hood, `findAll` uses eager loading, but `find` is lazy.

So findAll will fetch data from all related entites.

Find will only fetch Ids of relations, putting a proxy object in relation field.

If you want to have a full control, just implement findAll method in your entity repository using query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so I decided to only get some interesting fields from my customers.

Model:

```
public function getCustomerForApi($customerId)
    {
        $customer = $this->em
            ->createQuery('select c.name, c.lastname, c.address, c.phone, c.pass, c.tasks, c.email, c.status, c.location
            from OurentecBundle:Customer c where c.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $customerId)
            ->getResult();

        return $customer;
    }
```

And Controller:

```
/**
     * @return array
     * @Rest\Get("/customers/{id}")
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function getCustomerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $customerModel = $this->get('ourentec.customer_model');
        $customer = $customerModel->getCustomerForApi($request->get('id'));

        return array('customer' => $customer);
    }
```

It's not exactly what I want, but It will work fine for testing :)

Thanks a lot again Mateusz!!

Answer (score 0):

why not using  :

$customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('OurentecBundle:Customer')->findOneById($id);

Comment: I'll try it. With this other one in theory I just get only one result, but I get all database :S

$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('OurentecBundle:Customer')->findBy(array('id' => $id, 'isActive' => true)

Because there is only one $id in DB table (isActive is to know if customer has an incidence now)